# PHP Unexpected End of File

Tags: php

I am getting an unexpected end of file error on the last line of this code, I have run it through www.phpcodechecker.com (Which I have found do be very reliable).  What am I doing wrong? PHP version 5.5.9

```
<?php
/*  
  Hurricane Control Panel © 2014, a web control panel
  by Hurricane Development of http://www.HurricaneDevelopment.com
  is licenced under a Creative Commons
  Attribution-NoDerivatives 4.0 International License
  Permissions beyond the scope of this licence 
  may be available at http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nd/4.0/
*/

Defined("_HEXEC") or die ("This file may not be accessed directly");

class VARS {
  public static $errors = false;
  public static $extraJS = false;
  public static $scriptJS = false;
  public static $extraCSS = false;
}

abstract class GeneralUTIL {
  /**
  * Error functions
  **/
  public static function addErr($err) {
    VARS::$errors[] = $err;
  }

  public static function logger($content,$level = LOGGER_INFO) {
    if (!file_exists("logs")) {
      mkdir("logs");
    }

    $scanned_directory = array_diff(scandir("logs",SCANDIR_SORT_DESCENDING), array('..', '.'));
    $logs = false;

    if (sizeof($scanned_directory) == 0) {
      file_put_contents("logs/log.1", "", LOCK_EX);
      chmod("logs/log.1",0600);
      $logid = 1;
    } else {
      foreach ($scanned_directory as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos($value,"log.") !== false) {
          $logs[] = $value;
        }
      }

      $logid = explode(".", $logs[0]);
      $logid = $logid[1];

      if (filesize("logs/log." . $logid) >= 200000) {
        $logid = ((int) $logid) + 1;
        file_put_contents("logs/log." . $logid, "", LOCK_EX);
        chmod("logs/log." . $logid,0600);
      }
    }


    date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
    $d = getdate();

    file_put_contents("logs/log." . $logid, "{$d['mon']}/{$d['mday']}/{$d['year']} {$d['hours']}:{$d['minutes']}:{$d['seconds']} $level $content \n", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
  }

  public static function sha512($password,$salt = null) {
    if ($salt == null) {
      $cost = 50000;

      $salt = strtr(base64_encode(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM)), '+', '.');

      $salt = sprintf('$6$rounds=%d$', $cost) . $salt;
    }

    return crypt($password, $salt);
  }

  public static function matchSha512($password,$hash) {
    if (crypt($password, $hash) === $hash) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}

class PluginUTIL extends GeneralUTIL {

  public static function addJS($jsPath) {
    $debugArray = debug_backtrace();
    $pluginAlias = UTIL::getBetween($debugArray[0]['file'],"/plugins/plugin_","/");

    if ($pluginAlias == false) {
      UTIL::addErr("The addJS Method was not called from a registered plugin");
      return false;
    }

    $pluginLoader = new Plugins();

    $pluginLoader->loadPlugins();
    $plugins = $pluginLoader->getPluginsArray();

    foreach ($plugins as $id => $pluginArray) {
      if ($pluginArray['alias'] == $pluginAlias) {
        VARS::$extraJS[] = PATH . "plugins/plugin_" . $pluginAlias . "/" . $jsPath;

        return true;
      }
    }
  }

  public static function addScriptJS($script) {
    VARS::$scriptJS = $script;
  }

  public static function addCSS($cssPath) {
    $debugArray = debug_backtrace();
    $pluginAlias = UTIL::getBetween($debugArray[0]['file'],"/plugins/plugin_","/");

    if ($pluginAlias == false) {
      UTIL::addErr("The addCSS Method was not called from a registered plugin");
      return false;
    }

    $pluginLoader = new Plugins();

    $pluginLoader->loadPlugins();
    $plugins = $pluginLoader->getPluginsArray();

    foreach ($plugins as $id => $pluginArray) {
      if ($pluginArray['alias'] == $pluginAlias) {
        VARS::$extraCSS[] = PATH . "plugins/plugin_" . $pluginAlias . "/" . $cssPath;

        return true;
      }
    }
  }

}

class UTIL extends GeneralUTIL {

  public static function displayErrors($output) {
      if (VARS::$errors != false && is_array(VARS::$errors)) {
        $output = str_replace("<div id='errors' class='alert alert-danger'></div>","<div id='errors' class='alert alert-danger'><h1>Uh Oh.  Some errors occured!</h1>" . implode("<br>",VARS::$errors) . "</div>",$output);
      } else {
        $output = str_replace("<div id='errors' class='alert alert-danger'></div>","",$output);
      }
      return $output;
  }

  /**
  * Custom JS /CSS functions
  **/
  public static function addCustomJSFromPath($path) {
    VARS::$extraJS[] = PATH . $path;
  }

  public static function includeCustomJS() { 
      if (VARS::$extraJS != false && is_array(VARS::$extraJS)) {
        foreach (VARS::$extraJS as $key => $path): ?>
          <script src="<?php echo $path; ?>"></script>
        <?php endforeach;
      }

      if (VARS::$scriptJS != false): ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            <?php echo VARS::$scriptJS; ?>
        </script>
      <? endif;
  }

  public static function includeCustomCSS($output) {
      if (VARS::$extraCSS != false && is_array(VARS::$extraCSS)) {
        $css = "";

        foreach (VARS::$extraCSS as $key => $path):
          $css .= "<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"$path\">\n";
        endforeach;

        $output = str_replace("CUSTOMCSSAREAHERE",$css,$output);
      } else {
        $output = str_replace("CUSTOMCSSAREAHERE","",$output);
      }

      return $output;
  }

  /**
  * Get Between two strings function
  **/
  public static function getBetween($content,$start,$end) {
    if (preg_match('/' . str_replace("/","\\/", $start) . '(.*?)' . str_replace("/","\\/", $end) . '/',$content, $res) === false) {
        return false;
    }
    return $res[1];
  }

  /**
  * Redirect page function
  **/
  public static function redirect($location, $code = '302') {
    switch($code) {
      case '301';
        header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
        break;
      case '303';
        header("HTTP/1.1 303 See Other");
        break;
      case '404';
        header('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found');
        break;
    }
    //remove any &amp; in the url to prevent any problems
    $location = str_replace('&amp;', '&', $location);
    header("Location: $location");
    //kill the script from running and output a link for browsers which enable turning off header redirects *cough Opera cough* :P
    exit('<a href="'.$location.'">If you were not redirected automatically please click here</a>');
  }
}

?>
```

Comment: Have you tried dropping the closing `?>` and making the last line of the file `}`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this

```
<? endif;
```

to this

```
<?php endif;
```

inside `UTIL::includeCustomJS`

Comment: rogelio was fastest on the draw ;)

Comment: You are the greatest person ever

Comment: this is an ultra mega super duper known error.